# Running Java application on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, crud

I downloaded from github http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/ and import as maven and I cannot add this app to tomcat.
If i changed packaging from jar to war, I can add, but get 404 on localhost:8080/SpringBootCRUDApp

How can i run this app?

Comment: when i run your app i have error in console:

`ERROR 2998 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
`

have you same error?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

use [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/) example for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add it to tomcat. Spring Boot uses a public `static void main` entry-point that launches an embedded web server for you. So just run main method.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Application, you already added Springboot-starter-web Dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And packaged your application as "jar" as below in pom.xml

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

"spring -boot-starter-web" dependency has inbuilt embedded Tomcat container, so you don't need to add anything in Tomcat container

You can run your application with below command in cmd

java -jar SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample.jar